# How to extract sub-string from a string in a json file in dart/flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a huge json file which contains a field completely as a string. What i want to do is extract the sub-strings from that string and display them. I couldn't possibly find a solution.

"imp_fields": "['Starts\xa0immediatelyImmediately', '2 Months', 'Unpaid', "10 Jul' 20", 'Part time allowed']"

This is the field that i want to parse. I want all of these sub-strings separate. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you show the entire json object with brackets and curly braces?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own experiences, if you open your .json files in Google Chrome, you could use the [JSON Viewer Awesome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer-awesome/iemadiahhbebdklepanmkjenfdebfpfe?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

After you installed it, open up your .json file in Google, and then click your desired field, and then click the icon on the left corner, and choose `Copy Path`.

[image]

After that, you will get the path in this kind of form (based on the example picture above):

```
web-app.servlet[0]['init-param'].configGlossary:installationAt
```

To parse it in Flutter, you need to use `jsonDecode` provided in `Dart Convert` Package.
Example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  final myJson = 'Your json file source';
  final decoded = json.decode(myJson)['web-app']['servlet'][0]['init-param']['configGlossary:installationAt'];
  ....
}
```

Comment: The file doesn't open with JSON Viewer. Tried it.

Comment: Hmmm... It's weird. If you just drag and drop our file to Google Chrome, it should look like the picture automatically.